# java: xpath on json

Tags: java, web-services, json, xpath

I need a fast way to extract data from json responses a I get from a webservice.

By fast, I mean fast for the programmer, not necessarily for the computer.

I was thinking of something like Xpath for Json, if such a thing exists.

Any ideas? I am open to any Java Json library. In fact, the easiness to extract data from Json with a powerful querying language will be central to the choice of json library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Jackson JSON Processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) has been used in a lot of frameworks. The [tree model](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Tree_Model_Example) or data binding approach is probably the easiest to work with.

Comment: Codehaus appers to be discontinued.

Comment: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

seems to be a/the solution today.

Answer (score 1):

JsonPath emerged as a de facto standard for such tasks. A Java implementation:

https://github.com/nebhale/JsonPath

It seems well maintained and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

Similar to @alexis-dufrenoy's answer -- but it looks like a more active project.

Disclaimer: I have not tried @nebhale's system, so I can't judge which is best.